# How to remove my facebook tag seat from ticketmaster?

Tags: facebook

On the ticketmaster website it says at the venue that I'm going to that I'm sitting there but I don't want it there. Even when I click on don't show friends it shows up again after refreshing the page. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you have turned it off, then it shouldn't show up to others *but it still will for you*.  You can verify this in Facebook by using their **View As** function.  To activate this, click the security icon in the upper right corner of the screen (looks like a padlock with some lines).

You will see several options appear as a dropdown.  Click the one that says **Who can see my stuff?**  From the new options that gives you, click on the last one where it says **View as** and it will switch to viewing from the public perspective.

You can verify here that it has in fact hidden those details from everyone but you.  And if it turns out that they *are* still showing up... well, then you have a case for contacting the Facebook or Ticketmaster support teams.